# XML to custom Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm retrieving data from one vShield Manager via the API and building a database to syncronize with another...  I'm successfully retreiving XML from the API (yay) and I can parse it just fine, but it's a bit tedious.  I'm trying to create custom classes for the various objects in the vShield (virtual firewalls, global address objects, service definitions, etc.) so I can reference the data in my script in a sane manner, and this is where I'm running into a problem (sort of)...

I get xml back that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scopingObjects>
  <object>
    <objectId>datacenter-2</objectId>
    <type>
      <typeName>Datacenter</typeName>
    </type>
    <name>virtualDataCenter-01</name>
    <revision>5</revision>
    <objectTypeName>Datacenter</objectTypeName>
    <scope>
      <id>group-d1</id>
      <objectTypeName>Folder</objectTypeName>
      <name>Datacenters</name>
    </scope>
    <extendedAttributes/>
  </object>
  <object>
    <objectId>globalroot-0</objectId>
    <type>
      <typeName>GlobalRoot</typeName>
    </type>
    <name>Global</name>
    <revision>460</revision>
    <objectTypeName>GlobalRoot</objectTypeName>
    <extendedAttributes/>
  </object>
</scopingObjects>
```

And I itterate through that using ElementTree:

```
# Get the list of scoping objects
scopeObjects = [] # Declare an empty list
r = sendRest("getScopes")
xml = et.fromstring( r.text )
for object in xml.iter("object"):
    try:
        o = scope()
        o.create(et.tostring(object))
        scopeObjects.append(o)
    except Exception, e:
        print "Exception: " + repr(e)
```

Where I use the following class definition:

```
class scope:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = ""
        self.name = ""
        self.type = ""
    def create(self, xmlString):
        try:
            xml = et.fromstring(xmlString)
            if xml.find("objectId") is not None: self.id = xml.find("objectId").text
            if xml.find("name") is not None: self.name = xml.find("name").text
            if xml.find("type/typeName") is not None: self.type = xml.find("type/typeName").text
        except:
            print "Error constructing scope object from:\n%s" % xmlString
            return False
```

Which all works a treat... until I come across the more complicated XML structures... then it's an orgy of "if xml.find("blah/blah/blah") is not None: variable = xml.find("blah/blah/blah").text" over and over again...

I'd like to do something like:

```
class scope:
  def __init__(self):
    self.id = ""
    self.name = ""
    self.type = ""
  def create(self, xmlString):
    xmlPaths = { "id" : "objectId", "name" : "name", "type" : "type/typeName" }
    for key in xmlPaths.keys():
      element = xml.find(xmlPaths[key])
      if element is not None:
        # Set the class property named by "key" to the value of element.text
        locals()[key] = element.text
        # For example, if the key is "id", then it sets "self.id" to the text of the element in XML tag "<objectId>"
```

Basically, I want to be lazy when it comes to constructing the objects... I don't want to have to type loads of "if xml....".  It will become much more important when I start dealing with the more complicated objects returned by the API, with scores of elements to deal with.

My basic question: what's the best way to do this?

Cheers!

## My Solution:

Many thanks to Larsks for the answer.  Cheers mate!

```
class scope:
    xmlPathMap = {
        "id" : "objectId",
        "name" : "name",
        "type" : "type/typeName"
    }
    def __init__(self, element):
        self.element = element
        self.create()
    def create(self):
        try:
            for key, path in self.xmlPathMap.items():
                res = self.element.find(path)
                if res is not None:
                    setattr(self, key, res.text)
        except:
            print "Error constructing scope object:\n\tkey: %s\n\tpath: %s\n\tvalue: %s" % (key, path, res.text)
            return False
# End of scope class definition
```

Comment: Why are you calling `o.create(et.tostring(object))` and then in `create` immediately calling `xml = et.fromstring(xmlString)`? Why not just pass `object` without serializing/deserializing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?  This is basically what you're doing in your "I'd like to do something like..." example.  Attributes on `scope` objects default to None, and then get set using the attribute/xpath dictionary `xmlPaths`.  There's some stuff going on in your code that I'm not sure about (for example, I'm not sure what you're doing with `locals()` there), but I think this is doing what you want.

```
from lxml import etree


class scope(object):
    xmlPaths = {'id': 'objectId',
                'name': 'name',
                'type': 'type/typeName'}

    def __init__(self, element):
        self.id = None
        self.name = None
        self.type = None
        self.element = element

        self.parse()

    def parse(self):
        for attr, path in self.xmlPaths.items():
            res = self.element.xpath(path)
            if res:
                setattr(self, attr, res[0].text)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<scope id=%s name=%s type=%s>' % (
            self.id, self.name, self.type)


  with open('data.xml') as fd:
      doc = etree.parse(fd)

  scopeObjects = []
  for object in doc.iter('object'):
      o = scope(object)
      scopeObjects.append(o)

  print scopeObjects
```

Comment: Cheers mate!  The setattr function was exactly what I was looking for.  I'll edit my question with the solution I've adapted from your example.